# trying to install MySQL-python-1.2.3 but I get an error

Tags: python, mysql

Here tis the error I get while trying to install MySQL-python-1.2.3. any idea's?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Trying to install this on Python 2.7 on a windows xp machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and search for "MySQL-python". You'll find some pre-compiled packages of MySQL-python for Windows. Maybe one of them will be ok for you.

Using one of them (for Windows 7) was the only way I found to make MySQL-python work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. Its still frustrating that the official site would not post precompiled versions for python 2.7. I mean they have a precompiled version for 2.4 on the site :S

Comment: You're welcome. It really is frustating and it was a tiresome task to put MySQL to work with Python 7 in my machine. :-(

Comment: giving a thumbs-up was not enough. i had to write "thank you"

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step on how to get around this problem here: http://www.fuyun.org/2009/12/install-mysql-for-python-on-windows/